# Magento2 : How to change Grouped product child item template in cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, template, grouped-products

I have grouped products made of several child products.
I would like to change these childs template in cart.

I tried to modify checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml, but the original default.phtml template is called and not the one of my module :

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="grouped" template="Vendor_Module::checkout/cart/item/default.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped.actions" as="actions">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>  
</referenceBlock>
```

in default.phtml, when debugging, the product_type called is the child one. 
When I add to cart the same product but alone (not grouped), my template is loaded correctly. (I have the same overload for original type products)

How are child products templates called when in grouped product (in cart)?